# De-interlace video from Panasonic HDC-TM700 to remove flicker-lines

Tags: video, software-rec, video-editing, final-cut-pro

I wondered if anyone knew how to get the best result from de-interlacing the `.mts` video files from the Panasonic HDC-TM700 camcorder. I think my video has to much flickering

The camera is bought in Germany. I usually use ClipWrap to convert the files til `.mov`-files that can be read in Final Cut Pro.

Any tips on how to de-interlace to remove these flicker lines using Final Cut Pro or Compressor? Or any other third party software.

Answer (score 0):

I'm mainly deinterlacing movie / TV sources but if your encoding programme supports .avs AviSynth input source then you could look at either MCBob, TDeint or Yadif filters:

http://avisynth.org/mediawiki/External_filters#Deinterlacing

For Mac, you could try [Handbrake](http://handbrake.fr/details.php) which supports deinterlacing but haven't used myself (PC man) although I know others use it as their default encoder.

Comment: No problems, hope it fixes things. If you're looking for help on AviSynth specifics I'd advise checking out the Doom9 forums as they have a section dedicated to it.

Comment: Hi James, Unfotrunately I'm on a Mac, and it seems that AVIsynth is Windows-only.

Comment: Added Mac option for you ;-)